# SharePoint create and add users

Tags: sharepoint

I have installed SharePoint Farm on Windows Vista, all things went normally, my account is administrator. Now I wish to add other users in SharePoint, how to do this? I have to create a new account on Windows? or there are facilities for Windows SharePoint administrator to create users? I read something by Active Directory but on Windows Vista I have not found it.

Any ideas?

Comment: SharePoint doesn't have its own users, users always have to come from some other source. There are many such sources, such as active directory or a SQL database, but if you simply want to add a local windows user, that works too.

Comment: hmm and with SQL Database, I have to add the SQL User? or users from a table?

Comment: You can have form-based authentication if you want and use a regular membership system. Create a separate Web app for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add an user to your local users and groups in the machine and those users can be used in your sharepoint application

Comment: Yes, I've done that and it's working, but I want to have a table of users in a SQL database so I can manage users more efficiently. I think the best way it's form based authentication but I didn't ever worked with it and I'm afraid not to broke something..